# How does Windows determine which folder AppData local data goes in?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, application-settings, appdata

I know that local application data is stored in a set location on disk for my application:

```
c:\Users\jonathan\AppData\Local\MyCompany\MyApp_In_Question_Url_fhjsu6dhsj673dkncsdhjfdf
```

This contains several sub-folders containing the application settings (user.config), which generally take the form "6.1.5944.23465".

We do a straight file copy over the install location, and running the new executable from the shortcut on the desktop for the first time usually creates a new sub-folder of the same form (i.e. 6.1.5966.34567), which requires us to call Settings.Upgrade

So far, so good (although this probably isn't good practice).

I have just recently upgraded the application from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.6.2, and  on **some** machines it creates a new folder entirely:

```
c:\Users\jonathan\AppData\Local\MyCompany\MyApp_In_Question_Url_aaabf35hhsjd4hkwn83kfcm
```

And a new sub-folder of the form 6.1.5977.10245.

This is an issue because the shortcut on the desktop no longer works, and the settings cannot be upgraded, and require re-entry by the end-user (who doesn't always know them).

Most machines (all the test and UAT ones) do not exhibit this behaviour.

**My question is this:**

What is the mechanism for deciding that an executable's settings should be stored in an entirely new location, and not a sub-folder?

As a corollary of this:

Can I set this so that it's definitely the same product, and the settings can continue to be upgraded?

Comment: Problem has definitely been seen on WIndows 8, for reference.

Comment: I alredy faced this problem before, here is good "question", where gyu explains how to calculate settings folder https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad3e546d-21f1-4638-8409-bd59f7655f57/how-to-set-the-path-for-user-scope-settings-while-using-mysettings?forum=vbgeneral. In my case (the application was not signed) hash was base32 reresentation of the path. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339704/get-values-of-evidence-eid-and-hash-in-user-settings-path-construction is answer, how to get path of your configuration folder from your application

Answer (score 0):

I realised that sometimes the flow of code creates the first setting from a dll, and sometimes from the main executable, and I do some custom setting of My.Settings (in one of the VB chunks) which is a little messy.

In case you wondered: To recover the settings, I had to search through all the LocalApplicationData looking for my app's previous settings.

```vb
Private Shared Function FindFromPreviousSettings() As MigratableSettings
    ' Find the App_Data folder, and look to see if there are any other 
    ' config settings which are valid, authenticated, etc.

    Dim likelyConfigPath = New DirectoryInfo(
        Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
            "My_Software_Company"
        )
    )

    Dim allValidConfigs = SearchMyDirectory(likelyConfigPath, "user.config")

    Dim ver As Func(Of FileInfo, Version)
    ver = Function(fi)
        Try
            'Find out the version of this file. Bigger is better.
            Return New Version(fi.Directory.Name)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return New Version()
        End Try
    End Function

    Dim latestValidFile = allValidConfigs.OrderByDescending(ver).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim latestValidSettings = ReadSettingsFromConfigFile(latestValidFile)

    Return latestValidSettings
End Function
```